# Multiple v-for loops to display cities within countries?

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I am using vue.js and axios within visualstudiocode I'm very new at coding in principal and so I'm sorry if my question is worded poorly. I have two arrays I have assembled from this API:
 'https://docs.openaq.org/#api-_'

One is a list of countries, with data of how many cities is in the region etc, and another is a list of cities within those countries with corresponding data. I display a list of countries, in a table followed by a corresponding button in the same row using a v-for loop.

What I want to happen, is when this button is clicked for each corresponding country in the array, all the cities within that country will be displayed. I've been told this needs seperate v-for loops, but I don't know how I'd write it out.

```
<template>
  <div>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th>Countries</th>
    <th>Cities</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>   
     <ul>
      <li v-for="countries in listofcountries" :key="countries.name">
       {{countries.name}}
      </li>
     </ul>
    </td>
     <ul  v-for="countries in listofcountries" :key="countries.name">
      <li v-for="cities in lifeofcities" :key="cities.city"></li>
       <button>{{countries.name}}</button>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </tr> 
  </table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
 data () {
   return {
   listofcountries: [],
   listofcities: [],
   } 
  },
 mounted () {
 const axios = require('axios');
 var self = this;
// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('https://api.openaq.org/v1/cities') 
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response.data.results);
    self.listofcities=response.data.results;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });

  axios.get('https://api.openaq.org/v1/countries') 
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response.data.results) ;
    self.listofcountries=response.data.results;
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });
 },
 methods: {
   }
 }



</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
table,th,td,tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely certain this output is what you want but it's a place to start:

```
<template>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Countries</th>
      <th>Cities</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="country in countries" :key="country.key">
      <td>{{ country.name }}</td>
      <td v-if="areCitiesVisible(country.code)">{{ citiesInCountry(country.code) }}</td>
      <td v-else>
        <button @click="onClickCountry(country.code)">show cities</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cities: [],
      countries: [],
      countriesWithVisibleCities: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get('https://api.openaq.org/v1/cities')
      .then(response => (this.cities = response.data.results))
      .catch(console.log);

    axios
      .get('https://api.openaq.org/v1/countries')
      .then(response => (this.countries = response.data.results))
      .catch(console.log);
  },
  methods: {
    citiesInCountry(code) {
      return this.cities
        .filter(c => c.country === code)
        .map(c => c.city)
        .join(', ');
    },
    onClickCountry(code) {
      this.countriesWithVisibleCities.push(code);
    },
    areCitiesVisible(code) {
      return this.countriesWithVisibleCities.includes(code);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

It renders a table with one row per country. Each row has a name and a button. If you press the button, you'll get a list of cities instead of the button. Note that the API call seems to return only the cities for the first few counties in the list.

Other notes:

- Your original post had several typos that could have been caught with eslint. I recommend installing it along with prettier. I promise that will save you a lot of time in the future.
- I simplified the axios calls - `self` isn't necessary here.